# Include css file on slim framework project

Tags: css, slim

I'm trying to inlcude a css file on slim project but the file its not found even the path its correct ,maybe its a routing error??
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XrIN.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</body>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block scripts %}{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not open your png image, but I assume that your CSS folder file is on the same level as your index.php file so, try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body> ... </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: css file is on `/css`   and index.php its in `/src/public` and twig templates are in `/views`, `link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">` is not working

Answer (score 0):

Don't use relative path. Use absolute path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

This works when your `css` folder resides in the root of the public directory.

Comment: its on the original post ,click on the link , If Iuse `http://localhost/css/styles.css` doesn'r work because the route it's not recognized

Comment: Solved lacing css inside public folder

Comment: Sorry. I didn't check out the screenshot of the folder structure in the first place. Also, `css` should be inside the `public` folder.